# Convert Json to type script class [ts]

Tags: java, angularjs, typescript

i have the following Json

```
{"mapData":{"test":"success","publicKey":""},"statusCode":200,"message":null}
```

how to convert the following json to Type script class

the **mapData** have anonymes values

- it may be `{"test":"success","publicKey":""}`
- or it may be `{"test":"success","publicKey":"","anotherKey":"anotherValue"}`

***so how can we convert this json to type script object ?***

```
{"mapData":{"test":"success","publicKey":""},"statusCode":200,"message":null}
```

**My demo ts example**

```
export class GenericResponse {

 mapData: any;
 statusCode: number;
 message: string;
}
```

**The following are java class that i used to convert Object to Json**

```
/**
  * @author atwa  
  * Jul 2, 2018
  */
 public class Response {

/**
 * An Map that contains the actual objects
 */
private Map<String, Object> mapData =new HashMap<>();

/**
 * A String containing error code. Set to 1 if there is an error
 */
private int statusCode = 0;

/**
 * A String containing error message.
 */
private String message;


/**
 * @return the mapData
 */
public Map<String, Object> getMapData() {
    return mapData;
}

/**
 * @param mapData
 *            the mapData to set
 */
public void setMapData(Map<String, Object> mapData) {
    this.mapData = mapData;
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to create Typescript classes dynamically, as the JSON is received, or do you want to create them once and have them fit all different JSON structures? (Or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below approach.

```
  export class GenericResponse {

 mapData: any;
 statusCode: number;
 message: string;
 }
```

test.json is the below file

```
   {"mapData":{"test":"success","publicKey":""},"statusCode":200,"message":null}
```

In the TS file

```
   import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
   import { Http, RequestMethod, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, 
  RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

     import {GenericResponse} from  "../../model/genericResponse.model";
  export class genericSerivice implements onInit{

  genericResponse:GenericResponse;
  mockTesturl="assets/data/test.json"

  public getGenericResponse():  Observable<GenericResponse>{


   ngOnInit(){

   this.getGenericResponse()
  }

  let params: RequestOptionsArgs = {
     headers: new Headers({
    url: this.mockTesturl,
    method: RequestMethod.Get,
    '_id': new Date().getTime(),
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma':'no-cache',
    })
   };

    return this.http.get(this.mockTesturl, params)
  .pipe(map(res => this.extractGenericResponse(res)),
   catchError((error: any) => {
    if (error.status === 500) {
      return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
    }
    }))
  }

  private extractGenericResponse(res: any) {
 this.genericResponse = res;
}
```

[image: Response in the object]

Hope this helps